# accessing an object literal defined with jQuery onready from without

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have adopted a project that has several object literals defined - mostly for just structuring the code. Btw, not a full-time front-end developer. The problem is that some of them are defined with the jQuery onready event and some are outside. This seems really problematic to say the least. Would this be considered bad design? I'm assuming so. I have included a snippet of code that shows some of the problems, specifically the the from_inside function within obj2:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  alert('here i am' + obj2.handlers2.background2);  // can access the obj2 value as expected
  alert('make this up: ' + obj2.handlers2.tell_me2());
  var obj={};
  obj.handlers={
    background: 'blue',
    foreground: 'green'
  }
});

var obj2={};
obj2.handlers2={
  background2: 'here i am jt',
  foreground2: 'there you are',
  tell_me2: function(){
    return "these are things";
  }
  ,
  from_inside: function(){
    alert('color from inside jQuery: ' + obj.handlers.background); // problem here! could I get a reference to obj here?
  }
};

obj2.handlers2.from_inside();

</script>
```

Given how we currently have it, what would be a preferable workaround? It would seem like I could pass a reference of the jQuery object to obj2 in the above but perhaps it might just be simpler to pull all the objects outside of the jQuery on ready even if at all possible.

thx in advance for any advice

**edit #1**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(document).on('click','#pairing-comment-submit', function(){
    arc.event_handler.submit_pairing_comment.call(this);
  });
  ... about 50 more of these
});

arc={};
arc.event_handler={
  submit_pairing_comment: function(){
     var id=$(this).data('the-id');
     ....
  },
  ....
}
```

Comment: Just did a quick refactor. Let me know if that helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could move the variable assignment outside of the ready function. Here's a quick refactor:

```
var obj={};
obj.handlers={
  background: 'blue',
  foreground: 'green'
};

var obj2={};
obj2.handlers2={
  background2: 'here i am jt',
  foreground2: 'there you are',
  tell_me2: function(){
    return "these are things";
  },
  from_inside: function(){
    alert('color from inside jQuery: ' + obj.handlers.background); // problem here! could I get a reference to obj here?
  }
};

$(document).ready(function(){
  alert('here i am' + obj2.handlers2.background2);  // can access the obj2 value as expected
  alert('make this up: ' + obj2.handlers2.tell_me2());
  obj2.handlers2.from_inside();
});
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/JxS7v/

The problem you were facing was due to variable scope. Variables are scoped to the function in which they reside, generally speaking. Take a look at this article: http://javascriptplayground.com/blog/2012/04/javascript-variable-scope-this

Comment: Cool, thx Matthew, that was along the lines of what I was thinking. We unfortunately have a couple thousand lines of code; in all honesty, its not terrible - this jQuery wrapping of object literals is the worst part. Would that be a reasonable to handle it? Put all our capturing from selectors in a single onReady and then move the other pieces (ajax calls etc...) to different object literals like obj.location_edit, obj.location_show .... I know somewhat vague but would rather get some good advice now rather than later.

Comment: It's a little hard to say without seeing all of your code, but I generally try to keep as little code inside of the document ready function as possible. Like you're saying, set up your objects outside of the document ready, then interact only as necessary inside of the ready function. If you really want to do it correctly, you should refactor using modules: http://www.adequatelygood.com/2010/3/JavaScript-Module-Pattern-In-Depth

Comment: I should also say that you don't need to even put your selectors inside of the document ready. You can just invoke your objects or modules from inside the document ready, and the selectors will work just fine.

Comment: I think what you are saying is how we have it set up, if you could take a look at edti #1 above, I'd appreciate.

Comment: How you have it set up there should work because you are using .call() to set the scope of "this." However, I would move the document.ready to the bottom of your code so that arc has been assigned.